# HTTP response truncated in browser

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, axios

I'm making an HTTP post request using axios. The body of the response is a large 4MB string.

```
axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    headers : headers,
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

However, when I call this function from the browser, the response is truncated to 1024 characters (the full response is there in the Network tab).

Also, when I run this function in the terminal with Node, I get the full response.

How can I get the full response in my JavaScript code when running from the browser?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the `console.log` truncating..  have you tried `console.log(response.length)`?  Also you tried settings `timeout: 5000` and maybe `maxContentLength: 5000000`

Answer (score -5):

Why the hell do you receive a 4MB reponse after posting data ?

Except this, if you are in nodeJS side, just write the content of the response to a debug file

```
const fse = require('fs-extra')

const postMyAwesomeData = async function () {
    try {
        const firstCall = await axios({ method: 'POST', url, data, headers });
        // if you need more of those calls
        const responses = Promise.all([firstCall]);

        // responses.forEach does not handle very well async/await ^^
        for (let [index, response] of responses.entries()) {
            await fse.write(`<path to debug file>/response${index}.txt`)
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Hum something weird happen -_- ${err}`);
    }
}
```

Check out this awesome package https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra

But honnestly, what's the actual use case to retrieve such a big response after posting your data ?